# Does Error::description being soft-deprecated mean that I have to re-write my current error message system?

Tags: string, types, rust

I noticed that Rust [soft-deprecated `Error::description`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.description). It's recommended to use `Display` or `to_string()` to get my error descriptions, but does that mean that I have to re-write my current error message systems to handle `String` instead of `&str`?

I'm using this code and I've noticed code in the wild that looks similar:

```
fn description(&self) -> &str {
    match *self {
        Error::CannotDeriveFromHardenedKey => "cannot derive hardened key from public key",
        Error::Ecdsa(ref e) => error::Error::description(e),
        Error::RngError(_) => "rng error",
        Error::MnemonicError(_) => "mnemonic error",
    }
}
```

Comment: "Although using it won’t cause compilation warning, new code should use Display instead and new impls can omit it.

To obtain error description as a string, use to_string()." already answer you - -

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> does that mean that I have to re-write my current error message systems to handle `String` instead of `&str`?

No, it means that new or to-be-updated *implementations* of `Error` for your types should preferably disregard the method `description`. This means, do not add `fn description(&self) -> &str {}` in your `impl Error` cause, which appears to be what you were trying to do.

Implementing it may still be possible for the time being, but it is inherently restricted to returning a `&str`, which is indeed a limited signature.

Note that, as of Rust 1.42.0, this method is now [hard deprecated](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/03/12/Rust-1.42.html#errordescription-is-deprecated).